# Converting MySQL to PDO returns no results

Tags: pdo

I've been tasked with converting all MySQL queries to PDO. This has been fine, until this one query which doesn't work as expected in PDO form.

The MySQL version of the query, which works fine, is:

```
$queryPages = "SELECT m.member_id, p.page_id, p.live, p.version, p.page_title, p.page_locked_for_editing, p.form, p.folder_main_page, p.expire_date, DATE_FORMAT(p.published_date, '$DATESQL') AS published_date, p.author_id, m.firstname, m.surname FROM pages AS p LEFT JOIN members AS m ON m.member_id = p.author_id WHERE p.folder_id = '$folder_id' ORDER by p.folder_main_page DESC, p.page_id DESC";

$resultPages=mysqli_query(db_connect(), $queryPages);
```

The PDO version I've created is:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.member_id, p.page_id, p.live, p.version, p.page_title, p.page_locked_for_editing, p.form, p.folder_main_page, p.expire_date, DATE_FORMAT(p.published_date, ?) AS published_date, p.author_id, m.firstname, m.surname FROM pages AS p LEFT JOIN members AS m ON m.member_id = p.author_id WHERE p.folder_id = ? ORDER by p.folder_main_page DESC, p.page_id DESC";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$resultPages = $stmt->execute([$DATESQL, $folder_id]);
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the DATE_FORMAT part, but not sure how it needs to be changed.

Comment: Forgot to mention, $DATESQL is either

"%M %D %Y at %r"

or

"%D %M %Y at %r"

Comment: Is this very difficult or is my question badly worded?